# Omitting a border when there are 2 consecutive paragraphs

Tags: css, antenna-house

I've got a paragraph style that includes borders:

```
p.caution {
    border-top: 1.5pt double #FF0000;
    border-bottom: 1.5pt double #FF0000;
}
```

When my document contains 2 consecutive 'Caution' paragraphs, I'd like to omit the borders between those paragraphs. 
I want to omit two borders: border-bottom on the first paragraph and border-top on the second para.

So this is my desired result:

[image]

There doesn't seem to be a CSS selector that allows me to look at the next paragraph.
`border-collapse: collapse;` doesn't have the desired result either.

Is this possible? 
(I'm working on CSS Paged Media using the Antennahouse renderer, but this doesn't seem to be a Paged Media-specific question)

HTML snippet:

```
<div>
  <p class="other">some text</p>
  <p class="caution">some text</p>
  <p class="caution">more text</p>
  <p class="other">some text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an XSLT to modify my input HTML. I added an attribute to specify where I want a border to appear:

```
<xsl:template match="p[@class='caution']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:attribute name="border-after">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[1]/@class='caution'">no</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>yes</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="border-before">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::*[1]/@class='caution'">no</xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>yes</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

and in my CSS:

```
p.caution[border-after="yes"] {
    border-bottom: 3pt double #FF0000;
} 
p.caution[border-after="no"] {
    margin-bottom: 3pt;
} 
p.caution[border-before="yes"] {
    border-top: 3pt double #FF0000;
}
p.caution[border-before="no"] {
    margin-top: 3pt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following could be a solution:

```css
p {
  margin: 0; 
}

.caution {
  border-top: 4px double red;
}

.caution + .caution {
  border-top: none;
}

.caution:last-child {
  border-bottom: 4px double red;
}

.caution + p:not(.caution) {
  border-top: 4px double red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="other">some text</p>
  <p class="caution">some text</p>
  <p class="caution">more text</p>
  <p class="other">some text</p>
</div>
```

What this code is doing:

- Add a `border-top` to `.caution`
- If `.caution` is an adjacent sibling of another element with the class `.caution`, remove its top border.
- If `.caution` is `:last-child`, add a `border-bottom`
- If `.caution` has an adjacent sibling with no `.caution`class (which also means that it is not the last child, therefore the previous case won't apply) add `border-top` to the adjacent sibling.

This will work as intended with one, two or more consecutive `p.caution`.

Comment: Interesting approach, but by attaching the last border to `.caution + p:not(.caution)` it'll be difficult to get the spacing right in all cases.

Comment: Yes, indeed. You could still replace the default margin by custom paddings to solve this.

Comment: For example: `p {padding: 8px 0;} p:first-child {padding-top: 0;} p:last-child {padding-bottom: 0;}`

Answer (score 1):

**New answer**

You can try something like this:

```css
p.caution {
  border-top: 1.5pt double #FF0000;
  border-bottom: 1.5pt double #FF0000;
  margin:2px;
  padding:10px;
}
p.caution + p.caution {
  border-top-color:#fff;
  margin-top:-3pt;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="other">some text</p>
  <p class="caution">some text</p>
  <p class="caution">more text</p>
  <p class="other">some text</p>
</div>
```

---

**Old Answer**

If all the `p` are within the same container you can try something like this:

```css
p.caution {
  border-top: 1.5pt double #FF0000;
  margin:0;
  padding:20px;
}
p.caution:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1.5pt double #FF0000
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="caution">some text</p>
  <p class="caution">some text</p>
  <p class="caution">more text</p>
  <p class="caution">some text</p>
</div>
```

And with only one `p` it will also work fine:

```css
p.caution {
  border-top: 1.5pt double #FF0000;
  margin:0;
  padding:20px;
}
p.caution:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1.5pt double #FF0000
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="caution">some text</p>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

To omit all border between `p` you can try this:

```css
p.caution {
  margin:0;
  padding:20px;
}
p.caution:first-child {
    border-top: 1.5pt double #FF0000
}
p.caution:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1.5pt double #FF0000
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="caution">some text</p>
  <p class="caution">some text</p>
  <p class="caution">more text</p>
  <p class="caution">some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `border-top` be only for `p.caution:first-child`?

Comment: @IiroP it can be but it shouldn't ;) .. there is two differente settings and both are good, I will add this one too

Comment: I mean, currently there is still border between paragraphs which isn't what OP wanted.

Comment: @IiroP well, I understood that the OP want to omit one border ... maybe am wrong, let's see what they will say

Comment: There are more paragraphs with other styles in the same container, so it looks like I can't use first-child and last-child.

Comment: I want to omit two borders: border-bottom on the first paragraph and border-top on the second para.

Comment: @Hobbes I have edited my answer ;) the trick is to hide border by change the color of one and make it overlap the other

Answer (score 1):

If you promise to otherwise not use `::before` on anything that can follow a caution:

```
.caution {
  border-top: 1.5pt double red;
}
.caution:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1.5pt double red;
}

.caution + .caution {
  border-top: none;
}
.caution + *:not(.caution) {
  margin-top: -1.12em;
}
.caution + *:not(.caution)::before {
  border-top: 1.5pt double red;
  display:block;
  content: "";
  margin-bottom: 1.12em;
}
```

The `1.12em` is from `html.css` that comes with AH Formatter.  If you're using a different value, then you need to also use it here.

Comment: Interesting, but unfortunately I need the :before on some paragraph styles.